# OpenGL framebuffer error from glClear()

Tags: c++, opengl

I'm encountering an error developing an OpenGL application that I can't find any useful documentation for. When calling glClear() on a complete framebuffer, the OpenGL error GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION is set. There appear to be no side effects - the glClear call even works as expected. Regardless, it is throwing a lot of unnecessary errors that make it difficult to find a valid error.

The framebuffer is setup as such: (in this case, size is twice the display resolution)

```
glGenFramebuffers(1, &buffer);
glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, buffer);

textures = new GLuint[1];
glGenTextures(1, textures);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0]);
glTexImage2D(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, GL_RGBA, Size.width, Size.height, 0, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, 0);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_NEAREST);
glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

glFramebufferTexture2D(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_TEXTURE_2D, textures[0], 0);

renderBuffers = new GLuint[1];
glGenRenderbuffers(1, renderBuffers);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderBuffers[0]);
glRenderbufferStorage(GL_RENDERBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_COMPONENT, Size.width, Size.height);
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, 0);

glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_DEPTH_ATTACHMENT, GL_RENDERBUFFER, renderBuffers[0]);

auto state = glCheckFramebufferStatus(GL_FRAMEBUFFER);
if(state != GL_FRAMEBUFFER_COMPLETE)
    printf("Incomplete frambuffer: %d\n", state); //Never hit, framebuffer reports complete

glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, 0);
```

Then, when the framebuffer is bound:

```
glBindFramebuffer(GL_DRAW_FRAMEBUFFER, buffer);
glViewport(0,0,size.width, size.height);
glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT); //Sets GL_INVALID_FRAMEBUFFER_OPERATION error
```

This only occurs on Radeon cards so far, and only on seemingly random frames. If the scene doesn't change, the error typically will not recur.

Answer (score 0):

Eventually, we stumbled upon the solution to this. There was a call to glInterleavedArrays() in old code which was causing the call to glClear() to break in a nonsense way.

There's no obvious reason for this, so for now I assume it's a very specific driver bug.